# Make Div Background come over image

Tags: html, image, background

I am trying to make a div background come over image

A change image functionality similar to Stackoverflow

But i am not able to come it over the image even with a higher Z-index

```
<div class='sxlb'>
    <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Profile Picture:</label>
</div>
<div class="sxlm">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQu2JTWiJGx5MEdj5Tz7UUnqXjvkk8adgY9ayp9pwqJ8J-gAnCWjzPPaBBF8w" style="z-index:-1" />
    <div id="changeImage" style="color:black; text-align:center;display:none;margin-top:-20px; z-index:100;background-color:gray;"><a href="#">Change Image</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have made a sample demo fiddle for the problem

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b84QE/)

Please tell me what am i missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) doesn't work when the element is set with the (default) `static` `position`, but with `positioned` elements.

Anyway, you don't really need to use `z-index` if you set the inner element's position to `absolute`.

Look at [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/b84QE/2/).